# aws php script uploaded file permission issue

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a php site hosted in aws ec2 server.

While uploading files using php script it have only 0644(rw-r--r--) permissions in server. i need to change the file permissions to 0777(rwxrwxrwx).

What am doing is .. uploading a file and then read it and create a new encripted file using it and then delete the first file. its not happening because of file permission issue in aws uploading file through script.

uploaded files shows owner as 'apache' and transfer file using winSCP shows 'ec2-user'.

please help , am not much experinced in aws , so please please send your answers in detail.

Comment: Please show us the PHP code you're using.

Comment: ya show us please..

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName );
  
  //echo chmod(uploadaudios.$NewFileName, 0755);
  
  $in_filename  = uploadaudios.$NewFileName;
  $aes_filename = uploadaudios.$filename;
  
  $this->encryptFileCBC($in_filename, $aes_filename);
  unlink(uploadaudios.$NewFileName);`

Answer (score 1):

Try This one.
Hope it will work

```
move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName ); 
chmod($UploadDirectory.$NewFileName, 0755); 
$in_filename = $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName; 
$aes_filename = //your path to new file with name; 
$this->encryptFileCBC($in_filename, $aes_filename);
unlink($UploadDirectory.$NewFileName);
```

Comment: chmod not working , i alredy tried it.. thats y i commented it. i think it need some permission /owner ship settingds to apache user in aws server..

Comment: problem is related to aws server setting.. code perfectly working in local server

Comment: have you notice that i have chaged the `chmod` arguments

Comment: ohk so it a window based server or linux based server?

Comment: amazon aws ec2 server